# Liferay portlet deploy timestamp

Tags: javascript, liferay, portlet

I need to include some JavaScript in jsp pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/newsletter/js/newsletter.js"></script>
```

When I deploy a new portlet version and I change this JavaScript file, some users see the old version of this file.

I saw that Liferay adds last deploy timestamp to javascripts (`...js?t=14573725543`), and I can do it if I add this file to `liferay-portlet.xml`. But I can't do it with `newsletter.js`. Sometimes I need no load this file.

Is it possible to add manually this automatic timestamp? I do something similar in a theme with `$theme_timestamp`.

Comment: You know that _automatically_ and _manually_ are two contrary items? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay is using `com.liferay.portal.model.Portlet.getTimestamp()` to generate the number after `t=`. You can get the (Liferay) portlet from the PortletContext:

```
<%
LiferayPortletContext context = (LiferayPortletContext) portletConfig.getPortletContext();
long timestamp = context.getPortlet().getTimestamp();
%>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/newsletter/js/newsletter.js?t=<%=timestamp%>">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias, it's exactly what I was looking for!